# Style BasedOn a style defined in ControlTemplate Resources

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm using a 3rd party `ContentControl` which comes with the following theme:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type xyz:XyzControl}" x:Key="XyzControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type xyz:XyzControl}">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                  <Style TargetType="Button">
                     <!-- A lot of styling... -->
                  </Style>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <!-- More template stuff... -->
```

I want to add some `DataTriggers` to buttons inside this control but I want to keep the default styling from the control theme.

```
<xyz:XyzControl>
  <Button>
    <Button.Style>
      <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{???}">
        <Style.Triggers>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </Button.Style>
  </Button>
</xyz:XyzControl>
```

I tried to base on `{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}` but this loads the default global button style, not the default style in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible since you can't base a `ControlTemplate` on another `ControlTemplate`. You will have to re-define the entire template as a whole:

[WPF: Is there a way to override part of a ControlTemplate without redefining the whole style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570096/wpf-is-there-a-way-to-override-part-of-a-controltemplate-without-redefining-the)

And adding a trigger to a `Style` won't affect or "override" the triggers that are defined in the `ControlTemplate` of the control so you will have to override the entire `ControlTemplate` from scratch.

You could of course copy the default one into your XAML markup and edit it as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Add a key to the 3rd party's button style :

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:key="xyzbuttonStyle">
```

then :

```
<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource xyzbuttonStyle}">
```

Comment: Thx, but 3rd party is called 3rd party, because it's not my party :-) I cannot change that code.