# WPF Child control, style only content part

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inheritance, custom-controls

I have created a custom control called "Field", that inherits from `ContentControl` and that contains a `Grid` and a `label` to expose the field label, and a `ContentPresenter` to allow to put a control depending on the data we want to edit.

Then I created a custom control called "TextField", that inherits from `Field`, that should put a `TextBox` into the Content.

Here are the styles in Generic.xaml :

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:Field}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:Field}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <Grid x:Name="grd" Margin="3px">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Path=LabelLength, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Control}}" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Path=ContentLength, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Control}}" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Path=Label, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Control}}" />
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:FieldText}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type controls:Field}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:FieldText}">
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" MaxLines="1" TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

By evidence, this shows only a textbox when using a `TextField`. But how could I just style the content (eg the TextBox in this example) by keeping the rest of the control inheriting the parent style?

I know I could rewrite the whole control for each derivated control, but that's against the inheritence principles, no? Would mean duplicated code (duplicated markup here) and if I change anything in the parent "Field" I would have to change it in every child control, with the risk of errors...

Comment: You are saying yourself about putting TextBox into Content, but then you put that into Template overwriting everything.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Content` property of the parent control to an instance of a `TextBox` that you can style however you want:

```
<controls:Field Background="Gray">
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" MaxLines="1" TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
</controls:Field>
```

This is how a `ContentControl` is supposed to be used.

You *cannot* override only a part of a `ControlTemplate`:

[WPF: Is there a way to override part of a ControlTemplate without redefining the whole style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570096/wpf-is-there-a-way-to-override-part-of-a-controltemplate-without-redefining-the)