# Hiding the Up and Down arrows in the scrollbar of a scrollviewer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is there a way to hide these arrows in a scrollbar of a scrollviewer?
I couldn't find anything on google on how to disable these, if that's not possible then is there a way to change their color?

[image: these arrows]

Comment: You can customize the display by providing your own [ControlTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493644/controltemplate-for-datagrid-scrollbar)

Answer (score -2):

You need to set the `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` property of your `ScrollViewer`. The options are

- **Auto** - A ScrollBar appears and the dimension of the ScrollViewer is applied
  to the content when the viewport cannot display all of the content.
  For a horizontal ScrollBar, the width of the content is set to the
  ViewportWidth of the ScrollViewer. For a vertical ScrollBar, the
  height of the content is set to the ViewportHeight of the
  ScrollViewer.
- **Disabled** - A ScrollBar does not appear even when the viewport cannot display all of the content. The dimension of the content is set to the corresponding dimension of the ScrollViewer parent. For a horizontal ScrollBar, the width of the content is set to the ViewportWidth of the ScrollViewer. For a vertical ScrollBar, the height of the content is set to the ViewportHeight of the ScrollViewer.
- **Hidden** - A ScrollBar does not appear even when the viewport cannot display all of the content. The dimension of the ScrollViewer is not applied to the content.
- **Visible** - A ScrollBar always appears. The dimension of the ScrollViewer is applied to the content. For a horizontal ScrollBar, the width of the content is set to the ViewportWidth of the ScrollViewer. For a vertical ScrollBar, the height of the content is set to the ViewportHeight of the ScrollViewer.

Comment: The OP would like to remove the arrowheads, not the whole scrollbar.