# WPF DataGrid - Scrolling off of RowDetails jumps to next entry

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` which has a `ScrollViewer` in it´s `RowDetailTemplate`. I have implemented a handler for the `PreviewMouseWheel` Event and am forwarding the scroll to the `DataGrid` if the `ScrollViewer` hasn´t reached it´s `ScrollableHeight` or is at the edge of it´s `ScrollableHeight`.

This works but when the `RowDetails` take up most of the `DataGrid`´s view scrolling below the vertical offset of the current item just jumps to the next one rather than scrolling smoothly.
From what I understand the `ScrollViewer`´s `VerticalOffset` is in items rather than DPI if the `ScrollViewer`´s `CanContentScroll` property is `true` (which is the case here). I´ve tried scrolling by .5 rather than 1 but that does not work.

Is there a way around this? For example by forcing the offset into DPI mode or something like that?

Here is my DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgV" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext}" PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="dgV_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" CanUserSortColumns="True" CanUserReorderColumns="True" CanUserResizeColumns="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
          HeadersVisibility="Column" AlternationCount="2" >
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <!-- cut for brevity -->
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <!-- cut for brevity -->
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" MaxHeight="300" PreviewMouseWheel="ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel"MaxWidth="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UIElement}}" CanContentScroll="True">
                <!-- cut for brevity -->
            </ScrollViewer>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

And here is my handler:

```
private void ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    if(sender is ScrollViewer scrollViewer && !e.Handled)
    {
        if(scrollViewer.ActualHeight < scrollViewer.MaxHeight || (scrollViewer.VerticalOffset == scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight && e.Delta < 0) || (scrollViewer.VerticalOffset == 0 && e.Delta > 0))
        {
            e.Handled=true;
            var scv = ScrollViewerHelper.GetScrollViewer(dgV);
            if (scv != null)
            {
                var d = e.Delta / 120;
                //delta is always 120 which leads to a huge jump, apparently if cancontentscroll = true offset is in items rather than dpi
                scv.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scv.VerticalOffset - d);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

And here are some screenshots to demonstrate the issue:

Starting state:

[image: Starting state]

One scroll down:

[image: One scroll down]

The result i want:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `Template` for the whole `DataGrid` and use a `ScrollViewer` inside there. The `RowDetailsTemplate` only sets the details thing when you click on a row.

This example borrows from the link below and adapts it to yoru issue:
[ControlTemplate for DataGrid ScrollBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493644/controltemplate-for-datagrid-scrollbar)

```xml
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding List}">
            <DataGrid.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="DG_ScrollViewer"
                                  Focusable="false"
                                  CanContentScroll="False">
                        <ScrollViewer.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Button Command="{x:Static DataGrid.SelectAllCommand}"
                                            Focusable="false"
                                            Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                                            Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.All}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                                            Width="{Binding CellsPanelHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
                                    <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter x:Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter"
                                                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                                                    Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
                                    <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter"
                                                            CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}"
                                                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                                            Grid.Row="1" />
                                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                                               Grid.Column="2"
                                               Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                                               Orientation="Vertical"
                                               Grid.Row="1"
                                               Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                               Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                               ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" />
                                    <Grid Grid.Column="1"
                                          Grid.Row="2">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                                   Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                                                   Orientation="Horizontal"
                                                   Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                                   Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                   ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </ScrollViewer.Template>
                        <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
            </DataGrid.Template>
            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderThickness="0"
                            Background="BlanchedAlmond"
                            Padding="10"
                            Height="100">
                        <TextBlock Text="Lots of stuff..." />
                    </Border>

                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        </DataGrid>
```

This example should scroll smoothely since the `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll` property is set to `false`. This forces the DataGrid to use the Scroll Viewer to scroll instead.

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround that somewhat solves my problem. It still doesn´t fix the jerky scrolling but at least it solves the problem of the jump skipping parts of the `DetailRow` content.

Still, if anyone has an answer to the initial question please comment.

The workaround is limiting the `MaxHeight` of the `ScrollViewer` based on the `ActualHeight` of the `DataGrid` so that there are always at least 2 `DataGridRow`s visible.

`ScrollViewer`:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" MaxHeight="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource rowDetailsHeightConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}}" ..>
```

Converter implementation:

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //DataGridRowHeight / Header height = 25
        double targetHeight = (double)value - 100;
        return targetHeight > 30 ? targetHeight : 30;
    }
```

Comment: I just posted an answer that solves the smooth scroll entirely in the xaml without the need to try to deal with dpi scrolling and all that. Let me know if that's what you are looking for, or if not I can tweak accodingly.

Comment: @egeer thank you very much, it looks promising. I´ll try it out tomorrow and accept your answer if it works for me