# WPF Styles and Polymorphism

Tags: wpf, polymorphism, styles

I know I'm a pervert, but I am very curious, is there a way to make custom controls to seek for it's base class style first, and then it's own.
Why I'm asking: I have some TreeView derived controls with custom item templates. I apply those templates, then I have a base style. Later I might apply some color palette. At the last step I have a problem. I need to apply 2 styles. PVStructuralTree is derived from TreeView it has some DependencyProperty DataTemplates that get inserted into resources in code.

PVStructuralTreeView

- EmploeeTemplate
- ... more templates

Default style for PVStructuralTreeView:

```
<Style x:Key="DefaultPVStructuralTreeView" TargetType="{x:Type c:PVStructuralTreeView}" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultTreeView}">
    <Setter Property="EmploeeTemplate"><!-- This get inserted inro Resources in code -->
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type s:Emploee}">
                ...
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    ... Lots of them here
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type c:PVStructuralTreeView}" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultPVStructuralTreeView}"/>
```

Default style for a TreeView (it's pretty big, so I won't post it here):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultTreeView}"/>
```

In color template.xaml file I'd like to have this + some magic to apply both styles at the same time (from Generic.xaml and themed one):

```
<Style x:Key="ThemedTreeView" TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultTreeView}">
    ...
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type c:PVStructuralTreeView}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ThemedTreeView}"/>
```

But it just overwrites generic.xaml styles. I want it to add to it.

Now I'm doing this way:

```
<Style x:Key="ThemedPVStructuralTreeView" TargetType="{x:Type c:PVStructuralTreeView}" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultPVStructuralTreeView}">
    ... CopyPaste from ThemedTreeView ...
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type c:PVStructuralTreeView}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ThemedPVStructuralTreeView}"/>
```

Does anyone knows the way how to reuse the ThemedTreeView style here?

Comment: What I wrote here overrides the Generic style completely. I want to build on it, not to override. I am copying ThemedTreeView style into PVStructuralTreeView's style in template.xaml, when I'd like to build on existing, not to copy the code.

Comment: You can't base a Style on two other styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can base a `Style` on Another (one only!) `Style` using the `BasedOn` property and override specific properties, but you cannot base a `DataTemplate` or a `ControlTemplate` on another template. This is not supported. A template must be defined as a whole:

[WPF: Is there a way to override part of a ControlTemplate without redefining the whole style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570096/wpf-is-there-a-way-to-override-part-of-a-controltemplate-without-redefining-the/41570242#41570242)

Comment: You can't modify the template in a derived style. You can only set additional properties or "overwrite" ones set by the base style. So what is your current question?

Comment: PVStructuralTree is derived from TreeView it has some DependencyProperty Templates that get inserted into resources in code-behind.

Comment: Yes, I know about temlates. I was interested if there is a tricky way to base a style on two others. If not, then I'll stick to my CopyPaste way.