# WPF: How to override PART_CellBorder style of GridViewCell?

Tags: wpf, styles, radgridview, datagridviewcellstyle

I have a RadGridView and for one column/Cell of Grid, I want to change it's default "Part_CellBorder" style. I tried many things but I am not getting the proper way to do that.

Can anyone suggest what would be the proper way to dynamically change the style of Part_CellBorder (BorderThickness). Because I don't want to create separate style for this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't modify the `PART_CellBorder` element without creating a complete custom `ControlTemplate` for the cell, i.e. you will have copy the entire default `ControlTemplate` and then edit it as per your requirements.

The other option would be to try to *programmatically* get a reference to the `PART_CellBorder` element at runtime and then modify it by setting any of its properties. But there is no way to override only a part of a `ControlTemplate`:

[WPF: Is there a way to override part of a ControlTemplate without redefining the whole style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570096/wpf-is-there-a-way-to-override-part-of-a-controltemplate-without-redefining-the/41570242#41570242)